# Prove a polynomial is injection in unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

$P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k$ suppose $\sum_{k=2}^{n}|a_k|\leq |a_1|$ can we prove this polynomial is one to one in the unit disc $|z|<1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $P(z) = z + z^2$

Then $P(z) = P(w)$ if $z+w = -1$. For example, $P(-1/4) = P(-3/4) = -3/16$.

(Such a polynomial is injective on $|z| < 1/2$, though. That follows from the reverse triangle inequality.)